# How do I use F# FAKE's DropDb followed by a failwith?

Tags: sql, database, f#, f#-fake

When an error is thrown in one of my Target functions, I would like my application to first DropDb, then fail. But when I have the following code:

```
DropDb *databaseInfo* |> ignore
failwith "Migration failed"
```

The application fails before DropDb drops the database.

How can I make the application only fail once DropDb is complete?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I seem to have found the issue:

In my script, I have already ran DropDb before, then created a DB again. The code for DropDb in FAKE is:

```
let DropDb serverInfo = 
    if intitialCatalogExistsOnServer serverInfo then
         logfn "Dropping database %s on server %s" (getDBName serverInfo) (getServerName serverInfo)
        (getDatabase serverInfo).DropBackupHistory |> ignore
        getDBName serverInfo |> serverInfo.Server.KillDatabase
    serverInfo
```

`serverInfo` has been stored in a cache that was not updated by the script creating the databases again in my previous and therefore, `initialCatalogExistsOnServer` returns false and none of the code runs.